# How to change cell colour once selected in select element?

Tags: angular

I'm trying to change certain cells within a table depending on the value selected on a drop down menu, these values in the drop down are randomly assigned inside the cells of the table.

Each cell value has an assigned class that is equal to the vale in the cell. I want it so that when the value is selected in the dropdown the correlating cells with that value in change colour. So far I have:

app.coponent.html:

```
<div style="text-align: center">
<app-inputs (event)="getDataFromChild($event)"></app-inputs>
<p></p>
({{ colVal }}) cols and ({{ rowVal }}) rows
<p></p>
<select [(ngModel)]=val (ngModelChange)="value()">
    <option value="One">One</option>
    <option value="Two">Two</option>
    <option value=" Three">Three</option>
    <option value="Four">Four</option>
    <option value="Five">Five</option>
</select>
<p></p>

<table style="border: 1px solid black;">
    <thead>
        <tr style="border: 1px solid black;" *ngFor="let row of tableData">

            <td style="border: 1px solid black;" *ngFor="let column of row" class="{{ column }}">
                {{ column | uppercase }}
            </td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

app.component.ts:

```
import { Component, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { NgModel } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
 })
export class AppComponent {
   colVal: number;
   rowVal: number;
   randStr: string;
   randVal: any[] = [];
   tableData: any[] = [];
   randArr: any[] = ['One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four', 'Five'];
   val: string;

getDataFromChild(data) {
  this.colVal = data.columns;
  this.rowVal = data.rows;
  this.getRnd();
}

  getDataFromChildTwo(data) {
    this.randVal = data;
    console.log(this.randVal);
}

  getRnd() {
    this.tableData = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < this.rowVal; i++) {

      const values = [];
      for (let j = 0; j < this.colVal; j++) {
        const randNo = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);
        const storedVal = this.randArr[randNo];
        values.push(storedVal);
    }
    this.tableData.push(values);
    console.log(this.tableData);
  }
}
    value() {
     console.log(this.val);
   }
}
```

tl;dr - I want to change the colour of the cells that contain the selected option in the dropdown, I'm a little lost at the moment!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Template:

```
<td style="border: 1px solid black;" 
    *ngFor="let column of row" 
    class="{{column}}" 
    [ngClass]="{'selected': column == val }">
        {{ column | uppercase }}
</td>
```

and css:

```
td.selected {
  background-color: red;
}
```

**EDIT**

@ClutchBleu Answering your comment: `column == vall` checks if each `column` value associated with cell equals to `val` value binded to `<select>` using `[(ngModel)]`

Comment: Perfect! Could you briefly explain what the `column == val` part is doing?